# how to handle custom modules in Drupal migration from 7 to 9?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I'm upgrading drupal from version 7 to version 9.

I used drupal 9 migration modules for this, which worked well for drupal core and some contribs.  All content, users and datas are migrated.

But I have a couple of custom modules in the Drupal 7 project regarding functional requirements, does anyone know how to manage custom things in migration?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal community has written a guide about the best method to migrate data and code form Drupal 7 to Drupal 9 :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/writing-migrations-for-contributed-and-custom-modules

You can consider that everything that has been written about Drupal 8 is valid for Drupal, especially when the purposed code is using the new Symfony API.

When you rewrite your updated module, you have just to tel that it is complatible with Drupal 8 and Drupal 9 into `module.info.yml` file. The file will lokk like this and the last line concerns Drupal 8 and 9 compatibility :

```
name: Module name
type: module
description: Module description
package: Custom modules group name
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

The last important thing is that the module updated version will have to be ready before starting migration because the data migration classes will be included in it.